# Does anyone know how to create an Apple ID? Account creation is failing

Tags: apple-id

I'm a software engineer who's trying to create an Apple ID so I can download a copy of macOS that I can use for development - but, I'm not sure how to create an Apple ID - I'm, not smart, and, I need help.

I've tried creating an Apple ID via:

- The web browser; and
- The App Store on my MacBook Pro.

I've used two different networks to do this, but, alas, I have failed myself, and those around me.

Whenever I try to create an Apple ID via the web browser, account creation fails immediately after I submit the e-mail verification code - it says "your account could not be created at this time".

Whenever I try to create an Apple ID via the App Store, account creation appears to silently fail at the end of the process. It looks like there *might* be a pop-up raised immediately after I try to create an account, but, it disappears after 10-15ms and I can't tell what it says.

I've tried to create an account via each mechanism 3-5 times/each.

My e-mail address is `<name>@<name>.ca`, maybe that's not supported yet?

Does anyone know how this works?

Comment: You have a Mac without having ever used an Apple ID to even get through the initial setup?

Comment: It's a corporate device, I never had to set-up an Apple ID - maybe that's managed by our IT department - no idea, honestly.

Answer (score 2):

You should go to https://developer.apple.com and look for the Account link at top of the page. You should be able to create a free developers account. If you are developing for macOS or iOS you'll need this account sooner or later anyway.